# Reading a finite input from user through while loop into an integer variable

Tags: c++

I have just finished my first c++ program for my computer science class and I am stuck with a dilemma. The problem is within this while loop statement and it goes like this:

```
int main()
{
    int answer;
    while(!(std::cin >> answer)) // runs until number is read
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin >> answer;
    }
 // rest of code
    return 0;
}
```

Basically on the command prompt I get this undesired behaviour:

User input:

q

**5**

6

My program should have ended when it read the first 5(first number), but it doesn't and it prompts me to enter again for it to work.

Comment: `ignore` (without a parameter) just ignores one character. You probably want something like `std::cin.ignore(somenumber, '\n');`.

Comment: I think you need to rethink everything inside the while loop

Comment: why do you need a while loop if you only need to get one number using cin

Comment: I want while loop because if the guy enters a letter then it won't work.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson: Presumably, if the input is invalid, he wants to clear it and prompt again until he gets valid input.  Unfortunately, his logic is entirely backwards.

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger and watching what occurs on each line.

Comment: It seems I wrote in an extra cin in the while loop..forgot about that when I was editing it >.>.

Comment: The logic isn't entirely backwards, but it does repeat reading the answer where it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the line inside the `while` loop to read the number. When you have it, it's expecting another number after it successfully reads `5`.

```
while(!(std::cin >> answer))
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();

    // Remove this line.
    // std::cin >> answer;
}
```

**Update**

A cleaner way to deal with EOF and also to ignore the rest of the line, not just one character, when bad input is encountered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
   int answer;
   while(!(std::cin >> answer)) // runs until number is read
   {
      if ( std::cin.eof() )
      {
         std::cout << "Got to the end of input stream before a reading number\n";
         return -1;
      }

      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   }
   std::cout << "Got " << answer << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```